# updating var to already ran if statement

Tags: javascript

I have coded some if statement that should overwrite variable(of course if it is true), but it doesnt work...

On the beginning of the file I have these overwriting if statements
That 'sentOfferChanged' usually checks something happening only from some command(example: i have to say "!trade" to continue and call the offer, the command is coded with if statements)  that is written somewhere below this code, so at the first it store inside that variable "", but when I wrote the command and accept the trade, then this 'sentOfferChanged' will run but will not overwrite that command i want to be overwritten. So how can I automatically update it somewhere where it had first value and wont overwrite ?

```
var ifvartruefalse = "";
manager.on('sentOfferChanged', function(offer, oldState) {
 if (TradeOfferManager.ETradeOfferState[offer.state] === "Declined") {
  ifvartruefalse = "false";
  console.log('trade offer declined');
  return;
} if (offer.itemsToGive.length == 0){
    if (offer.state == TradeOfferManager.ETradeOfferState.Accepted){
      console.log("trade offer accepted");
     ifvartruefalse = "true";

    }
  }
});
```

under them I have if statement that run depending how they are overwritten, in front of them is the command built with if statements, so only if i write command this will happen

```
console.log(ifvartruefalse);

if (ifvartruefalse === "false"){
  message.reply('<:false:750799883572609245> **Trade was declined, deleting the coinflip**');
  return;
}

if (ifvartruefalse === "true"){
  message.channel.send('<:true:750799921497505913> **Trade was succesfully confirmed**, generating random ticket from 0 to 100');
```

this is really hard to explain so sorry. If you wont understand something, tell me .

.
Just little example what it does wrongly[image: console and messages]
When in console is trade accepted the bot should say in messages something like " trade was accepted"

Comment: You really need to pick better variable names. Also, use `let` or `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the variable assignments. Something in your app must not be working as expected.

Comment: if I share the code, could you find it ??

Comment: Maybe it's because you're setting the value to an empty string and then checking for the string `false`. They're not equivalent, and if neither of your `if` statement conditionals apply it won't be updated.

Comment: i think thats good because the false is in strings

Comment: Maybe use `if() {} else {}` rather than two explicit if conditions.

Comment: still wont work

Comment: Set breakpoints in the Sources tab inside every if statement and see what's happening. We won't be able to help debug your business logic from what we know. You'll see what's not working as expected.